# run multiple sql query from excel VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple sql query in column c of worksheets("query") where the number of query can change. When there is a cell containing a sql query i want my code to run them one by one and populate the data in another worksheets("RESULT")

the final outcome would be :

run sql query number 1 and get result with the header in sheet RESULT (result will be sperad from range("A:M")

run sql query number 2  and get the reuslt in sheet RESULT right after the result 1 (whithout the hearder)

run sql query number 3  and get the result in sheet RESULT right after the result 1 &2 ( without the header)
...
...
...
...
...
run sql query number x  and get the result in sheet RESULT right after the result 1 to x ( without the header)

[image]

[image]

```
Sub DCPARAMS()
 Dim DBcon As ADODB.Connection
    Dim DBrs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set DBcon = New ADODB.Connection
    Set DBrs = New ADODB.Recordset

Dim SSDF_SSDF As Workbook


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

   Dim DBQuery As String
    Dim ConString As String
    Dim SQL_query As String
    Dim User As String
    Dim Password As String
    Dim RowsCount As Double
            
    Dim intColIndex As Double
    
    DBrs.CursorType = adOpenDynamic
    DBrs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    
Windows("SSDF MACRO.xlsm").Activate
Set SSDF_SSDF = ActiveWorkbook
        
 User = SSDF_SSDF.Sheets("MACROS").Range("B4").Value
 
 Password = SSDF_SSDF.Sheets("MACROS").Range("B5").Value


'error handling
On Error GoTo err
'I WANT THIS VALUE TO CHANGE BASED ON QUERY SHEETS COLUMN C
**SQL_query = Worksheets("query").Range("C2").Value**

' DELETING OLD VALUES


SSDF_SSDF.Sheets("RESULT").Select
SSDF_SSDF.Sheets("RESULT").Range("A1:Q1000000").Select
Selection.ClearContents
If User = "" Then MsgBox "Please fill in your user ID first"
If User = "" Then Exit Sub
If Password = "" Then MsgBox "Please fill in your Password first"
If Password = "" Then Exit Sub

'Open the connection using Connection String
    DBQuery = "" & SQL_query
    ConString = "Driver={Oracle in OraClient12Home1_32bit};Dbq=prismastand.world;Uid=" & User & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"
    DBcon.Open (ConString) 'Connecion to DB is made
'below statement will execute the query and stores the Records in DBrs
    DBrs.Open DBQuery, DBcon
     
    If Not DBrs.EOF Then 'to check if any record then
' Spread all the records with all the columns
' in your sheet from Cell A2 onward.
        SSDF_SSDF.Sheets("RESULT").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset DBrs
'Above statement puts the data only but no column
'name. hence the below for loop will put all the
'column names in your excel sheet.
      For intColIndex = 0 To DBrs.Fields.Count - 1
           Sheets("RESULT").Cells(1, intColIndex + 1).Value = DBrs.Fields(intColIndex).Name
      Next
        RowsCount = DBrs.RecordCount
    End If
   
    
   
'Close the connection
    DBcon.Close
    
'Informing user
       Worksheets("REUSLT").Select
If Range("A2").Value <> "" Then
    MsgBox "ALL GOOD, RUN NEXT MACRO"
    Else: MsgBox "DATA IS MISSING IN DB PLEASE CHECK"
 Exit Sub
End If
    
    'alerts
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Windows("SSDF MACRO.xlsm").Activate
SSDF_SSDF.Sheets("dc").Select
    Exit Sub
err:
    MsgBox "Following Error Occurred: " & vbNewLine & err.Description
    DBcon.Close
    'alerts
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

I tired to run the code attached but it get only the sql query in cells c2. Iam sorry im very novice

Answer (score 0):

Define a range for the results and offset it by the number of rows returned.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DCPARAMS()

    Const WBNAME = "SSDF MACRO.xlsm"

    Dim DBcon As ADODB.Connection, DBrs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim SSDF_SSDF As Workbook, wsResult As Worksheet, wsQuery As Worksheet
    Dim rngResult As Range
    Dim ConString As String, SQL_query As String
    Dim User As String, Password As String
    Dim intColIndex As Long, lastrow As Long, r As Long
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
    Windows("SSDF MACRO.xlsm").Activate
    Set SSDF_SSDF = Workbooks(WBNAME)
    With SSDF_SSDF
        Set wsResult = .Sheets("RESULT")
        Set wsQuery = .Sheets("Query")
    End With
    
     'error handling
    On Error GoTo err
    
    ' connect to db
    With SSDF_SSDF.Sheets("MACROS")
        User = .Range("B4").Value
        Password = .Range("B5").Value
        If User = "" Or Password = "" Then
            MsgBox "Please fill in your user ID and password", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    
    ConString = "Driver={Oracle in OraClient12Home1_32bit};Dbq=prismastand.world;" & _
                "Uid=" & User & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"
    
    Set DBcon = New ADODB.Connection
    DBcon.Open ConString 'Connecion to DB is made

    Set DBrs = New ADODB.Recordset
    DBrs.CursorType = adOpenDynamic
    DBrs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
     
    ' delete old results
    With wsResult
         .Range("A:Q").ClearContents
         Set rngResult = .Range("A2")
    End With
       
    With wsQuery
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        
        For r = 2 To lastrow
        
            'I WANT THIS VALUE TO CHANGE BASED ON QUERY SHEETS COLUMN C
            SQL_query = .Cells(r, "C")
            
            'below statement will execute the query and stores the Records in DBrs
            DBrs.Open SQL_query, DBcon
            
            If Not DBrs.EOF Then 'to check if any record then
            
                'Above statement puts the data only but no column
                'name. hence the below for loop will put all the
                'column names in your excel sheet.
                If wsResult.Cells(1, 1) = "" Then
                    For intColIndex = 0 To DBrs.Fields.Count - 1
                       wsResult.Cells(1, intColIndex + 1) = DBrs.Fields(intColIndex).Name
                    Next
                End If
                      
                ' Spread all the records with all the columns
                ' in your sheet from Cell A2 onward.
                rngResult.CopyFromRecordset DBrs
                
                ' move down for next query
                Set rngResult = rngResult.Offset(DBrs.RecordCount)
                
            End If
            DBrs.Close
        Next
    End With
       
    'Close the connection
    DBcon.Close
        
    'Informing user
    If wsResult.Range("A2").Value <> "" Then
        MsgBox "ALL GOOD, RUN NEXT MACRO", vbInformation, "Rows = " & rngResult.Row - 2
    Else:
        MsgBox "DATA IS MISSING IN DB PLEASE CHECK", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    SSDF_SSDF.Activate
    SSDF_SSDF.Sheets("dc").Select
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
err:
    MsgBox "Following Error Occurred: " & vbNewLine & err.Description
    DBcon.Close
    'alerts
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   
End Sub
```